# Stripe error: "The card object must have a value for 'number'" when creating a Customer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe's ruby gem to (try to) perform two steps:

1. Collect a card using Stripe's "Checkout" form
2. Create a Customer using the token provided by the redirect from the form submission

The latter of these steps raises a `Stripe::CardError` whose message is:

> The card object must have a value for 'number'

The API doc describes the process: https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/subscriptions#subscribing-a-customer-to-a-plan

**My code (a Rails controller action)**

```
def receive_redirect
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      plan: "stripe_plan_name",
      card: params[:stripeToken]
    )
end
```

**params[:stripeToken] looks like this:**

> {"id"=>"tok_1044TY4GgNdNSosPXdAmIZdt", "livemode"=>"false",
>   "created"=>"1400620581", "used"=>"false", "object"=>"token",
>   "type"=>"card", "card"=>{"id"=>"card_1044TY4GgNdNSosPuDSuygow",
>   "object"=>"card", "last4"=>"9424", "type"=>"Discover",
>   "exp_month"=>"9", "exp_year"=>"2014",
>   "fingerprint"=>"Lz5ASwlmyseG0gYo", "customer"=>"", "country"=>"US",
>   "name"=>"manderson@pinneyinsurance.com", "address_line1"=>"",
>   "address_line2"=>"", "address_city"=>"", "address_state"=>"",
>   "address_zip"=>"", "address_country"=>""},
>   "email"=>"<my_email>@<my_host>"}

...As you can see, they don't give me a number, so what am I to do?

**Stack**

stripe 1.8.8 (ruby gem)
Rails 3.2.13
Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The value you should be setting `card:` to is just the id of the token and not the entire object you are passing right now.  Something like this (my ruby is a bit rusty):

```
card: params[:stripeToken][:id]
```

You can see an example of valid inputs to `Customer.create` in the [Stripe API Docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#create_customer).

Comment: I guess you're right. Every code example in the reference doc appears to be wrong in this respect.

Comment: Double-check your checkout code—using Stripe's sample code, `stripeToken` most definitely should be a simple string containing a token ID. That looks like the token's been looked up via the API for some reason.

Comment: @colinm Unfortunately Stipe's examples are pretty bad. For instance in this case their example shows: `customer.source = stripe_token`  What it should say is: `customer.source = stripe_token[:id]` There's no indication that it wants the id not the whole token. The error message when you give it the whole token is even worse: "must specify object type" That leads you down a rabbit hole of trying to give it the card object.